# Erro ao tentar declarar o tipo de uma variável proveniente de um relacionamento dentro de um método listar

Tags: java

Boa tarde, estou com um problema em setar a variável [fornecedor] em um método [listarProduto] que é do ProdutoDAO, e quero receber o atributo [id] do fornecedor.

Aonde tentar setar o tipo da variável dá erro em [rs.getInt("fornecedor")] e é informado pelo netbeans que [incompatible types int cannot be converted to Fornecedor] como se ela não aceitasse declarar o id que vem de fornecedor como int.

Mas essa classe `produto` tem que se relacionar com o `fornecedor`, porque como estou tentando fazer para uma interface gráfica aonde eu vou utilizar essas informações obtida através `combobox` ou `jtable` em um `jframe` de cadastrar produto, para quando eu clicar em um dos dois ele possa listar automaticamente os nomes dos `fornecedores` e os `id` para eu escolher e depois cadastrar o produto com o resto das informações. Então não posso tirar o relacionamento da variável `Fornecedor fornecedor` e declarar ela como `Int`.

peço desculpas se não conseguir informa direito o problema primeira vez aqui.

Essa é minha classe fornecedor

```
public class Fornecedor {
    
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String cnpj;
    private String fone;
    private String email;
    private String ie;
    private String cep;
    private String cidade;
    private String uf;
    private String endereco;

   
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }  
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }   
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }   
    public String getCnpj() {
        return cnpj;
    }  
    public void setCnpj(String cnpj) {
        this.cnpj = cnpj;
    }   
    public String getFone() {
        return fone;
    }  
    public void setFone(String fone) {
        this.fone = fone;
    }  
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    } 
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    } 
    public String getIe() {
        return ie;
    }  
    public void setIe(String ie) {
        this.ie = ie;
    } 
    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }  
    public void setCep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    } 
    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    } 
    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    } 
    public String getUf() {
        return uf;
    }
    public void setUf(String uf) {
        this.uf = uf;
    }
    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }
    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }
}
```

Essa é minha classe Produto

```
public class Produtos {
    
    private int idProd;
    private String nome;
    private String unidade;
    private int precoDeCompra;
    private int precoDeVenda;
    private Fornecedor fornecedor;
    //private String fornecedor;
    private String estoque;

 
    public int getIdProd() {
        return idProd;
    }

    public void setIdProd(int idProd) {
        this.idProd = idProd;
    }


    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }


    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }


    public String getUnidade() {
        return unidade;
    }


    public void setUnidade(String unidade) {
        this.unidade = unidade;
    }


    public int getPrecoDeCompra() {
        return precoDeCompra;
    }


    public void setPrecoDeCompra(int precoDeCompra) {
        this.precoDeCompra = precoDeCompra;
    }


    public int getPrecoDeVenda() {
        return precoDeVenda;
    }


    public void setPrecoDeVenda(int precoDeVenda) {
        this.precoDeVenda = precoDeVenda;
    }


    public Fornecedor getFornecedor() {
        return fornecedor;
    }


    public void setFornecedor(Fornecedor fornecedor) {
        this.fornecedor = fornecedor;
    }


    public String getEstoque() {
        return estoque;
    }


    public void setEstoque(String estoque) {
        this.estoque = estoque;
    }
    
}
```

E esse é o metodo listar em ProdutosDAO que ocorre o erro

```
public List<Produtos> listarProdutos(){
        try {
            List<Produtos> lista = new ArrayList<>();
            
            String sql = "select * from produtos";
            
            PreparedStatement stm = conProd.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
            
           while (rs.next()){
               Produtos obj = new Produtos();
               
               obj.setIdProd(rs.getInt("idProd"));
               obj.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
               obj.setUnidade(rs.getString("unidade"));
               obj.setPrecoDeCompra(rs.getInt("precoDeCompra"));
               obj.setPrecoDeVenda(rs.getInt("precoDeVenda"));
               obj.setFornecedor(rs.getInt("fornecedor"));//o erro dá na parte rs.getInt("fornecedor")
               obj.setEstoque(rs.getString("estoque"));
               
               
               lista.add(obj);
                
           }
           return lista;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao listar Produtos: "+e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Está tentando fazer um `getInt` em uma variável que possui o tipo `Fornecedor`.

Comment: Por que não produto.getFornecedor().getId()?

Comment: @epx eu tentei fazer isso obj.getFornecedor.getId((rs.getString("fornecedor"))); e obj.getFornecedor.getId(rs.getString("fornecedor")); e deu esse erro [link](https://prnt.sc/1tdha3t)

Comment: @Danizavtz s, mas eu não sei qual tipo usar para puxar a informação id do fornecedor

Comment: Tem que ser o tipo que está na Descrição da coluna `fornecedor` da tabela `produtos`. Verifique o DDL da tabela `produtos`.

Comment: @Danizavtz peço desculpa por n saber oque é DDL, mas na classe produto eu atribuir fornecedor como fornecedor para ter uma variavel que possa acessar todas as informações de fornecedor, mas como eu só queria salvar o id eu coloquei como int no metodo listar pq é como eu declarei o id na classe fornecedor, se eu não entendi oque vc quis falar peço desculpa

Comment: Então não seria só mudar o tipo da variável  `private Fornecedor fornecedor;` para `int`? Exemplo: `private int fornecedor;` e depois mudar getter e setter.

Comment: @Danizavtz sim assim resolveria, mas essa classe `produto` tem que se relacionar com o `fornecedor`, porque como estou tentando fazer para uma interface gráfica aonde eu vou utilizar essas informações obtida através `combobox` ou `jtable` em um `jframe` de cadastrar produto, para quando eu clicar em um dos dois ele possa listar automaticamente os nomes dos `fornecedores` e os `id` para eu escolher e depois cadastrar o produto com o resto das informações. Só q eu não sei se vou ter como fazer isso só colocando `int` e não o relacionamento

Comment: Poderia adicionar estas informações que adicionou nos comentários na pergunta? Assim podemos ser mais assertivos quando responder. Agora está claro qual o problema. Você pode editar a pergunta para incluir as informações. Clicando em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/528817/edit)

Comment: @Danizavtz peço desculpa por não saber como fazer a pergunta, é a minha primeira vez fazendo alguma pergunta relacionada a programação desde que comecei a programar, se vc poder me dizer se falto colocar algo ou mudar alguma coisa pf me avisa que como é minha primeira vez aq não sei como fazer as coisas direito ainda

Comment: O que usa pra fazer o mapeamento? JPA?

Comment: @Danizavtz na verdade eu não utilizo nada para mapear como hibernate ou JPA, esse trabalho é só utilizando comandos para o mysql e fazer um crud basico para interface grafica, então oque eu estou utilizando para tentar pegar as informações é precisamente essa variável fornecedor que fica dentro do object produto

Comment: @Danizavtz afinal esse projeto não utiliza controller nem regras de negocio, então por isso que é mais simples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se quer numa só consulta do seu DAO trazer o produto junto com os dados do fornecedor, precisa mexer no seu SQL.

`Select * from produtos` traz só uma lista de produtos sem indicação de qual produto deseja e nem quem são os fornecedores (só os id's de fornecedor na tabela produtos). Essa consulta em SQL não está referenciando a tabela `fornecedores` e não está fazendo nenhuma associação entre o produto e o fornecedor, que seria um `where produto.id_fornecedor = fornecedor.id`, por exemplo.

Esse é só o erro principal, tem outros. A modelagem de estoque está ruim. Pense muito bem o que quer dizer com estoque. Na tabela produtos, cada registro (linha) é um produto, representado por um objeto da classe que deveria estar com o nome no singular (Produto). Estoque de um produto é o quê? Uma coluna que guarda um valor inteiro? Ou seu estoque é uma lista de produtos de determinado tipo? Qual fica melhor no seu caso? Entre alguma outra eventual possibilidade.